# How to stop windows from going back to qwerty

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have dvorak as my default. Yet windows sometimes decides ( annoingly usually while I'm playing games, not coding ) to default back to qwerty. I cannot seem to permanently remove it as even removing all the languages left doesn't stop windows from thinking I really love qwerty.

If it shows 1 option, still qwerty is available in the little toolbar item and it will accidentally switch sometimes. How can I stop this?

Comment: +1 You wrote "I have dvorak as my default"     Though perhaps this may be worth considering https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1071357  ___"The QWERTY vs Dvorak argument is silly; both were designed at a time before any research had been performed into typing ergonomics, and the only reason to pick one or the other is largely based on hearsay and rumor."  _______       That said, there may be some truth to the idea that a top row that is an anagram of the word typewriter could perhaps be improved significantly with a bit of key rearrangement.

Comment: I learned it when I had a day free, after that I always preferred it. I don't really care what other people want to use. I just want to use my keyboard layout. I can still type in qwerty just fine I just don't like it. Windows is the only OS that is trying to be a bitch about it too.

Comment: in win7 if do start..region and language..change keyboards, then I get this screen  https://i.imgur.com/eVbdPik.png   can you get this screen and include a pic of it and show what is the default.. and are you saying that this changes? Also what if you try adding a new language, does the game cause a change of language?  a program can change the language and perhaps layout.

Comment: I see some weird behaviours in win7, e.g. if I am on language A, and click for another language in the language bar, language B,  then I click bottom left, then it changes back to the language that was.  You're saying you even tried deleting all languages.. and it sitll does that..I find that strange.I don't have a system to experiment iwith right now..but how about you include in your question the method you used to add Dvorak as a language or layout? (that will help others to reproduce it). And you could include a screenshot of your language bar too, besides the other screenshot I mentioned.